# Query Function - remove parts of entered term and carry out formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, search, worksheet-function

I'm sorry if the title is confusing.
In the **List to Search** tab, I've got a bunch of orders. What I do is select the dishes in a single cell in this manner:

[image]

And I want to just dump them into the column A, dishes search section in **Search for Dish** tab. And the query should grab the relevant dishes from the Inventory tab, omitting the numbers before the dish name, i.e. "1_" or "1___". Basically just omit that part and only get the dish name without me having to do any extra work.

The numbers before the dishes would be in either of these 2 patterns mostly, "1_" or "1___".

If this detail helps, all dishes have an index number in this format `D00 -`  or `D000 -`

This is the basic routine for my work, the copying of dishes from a single cell, so its important that I be able to just grab only the dish name with index number.

This is my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlATwRPTkofEg0rB5-GSwwBpQDa7ZOoeNvhs0xPOsKA/edit#gid=719800634

*I've tried INDIRECT & TRIM in the query formula like this: `"where A='"&INDIRECT(A3)&"`, but they didn't work. Maybe the way I entered them were wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned

> ...select the dishes in a single cell in this manner:   ...just dump
> them into the column `A`, dishes search section in `Search for Dish`
> tab    ...query should grab the relevant dishes from the `Inventory`
> tab, omitting the numbers before the dish name

Place the following in cell `B3` in your `NEW Search for Dish` tab.

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(
           SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE($A$3, ".*?(?:(D\d+\s- \w+ \w+))","$1"),CHAR(10))), 
     "Paste the order in cell A3")
```

[image]

The above formula will do the work for you.
*(Please adjust ranges to your needs. You can find a demo in your sheet.)*

**How to copy/paste for the formula to work.**
Please **do NOT double click** the cell to copy the dishes.
**Just single click on a cell**, copy and paste it on cell `A3` in your `NEW Search for Dish` tab.

Comment: You saved the day again for me! Thank thank thank, you so much! :D

Comment: Glad I could help. But remember. I'll be back  for my recipes. :)